# PHP | Every other year

Tags: php, date

I need a php script that performs a task every other year from a given start date variable.

Examples:

```
$start_year = 2011 and $current_year = 2016 => don't perform task
$start_year = 2012 and $current_year = 2016 => perform task
$start_year = 2013 and $current_year = 2016 => don't perform task
$start_year = 2014 and $current_year = 2016 => perform task
$start_year = 2015 and $current_year = 2016 => don't perform task
```

How do I check if the current year is within the every other year interval from the start date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just substract the start year to the current one and check if its even or odd.

```
   if((($current_year - $start_year) % 2) == 0){
    //perform task
    }
```